# Chart position in highchart

Tags: html, css, highcharts

I create 2 highcharts i.e.

```
<div>
   <p id="container">
   </p>
   <p id="cont">
   </p>

   </div>
```

i set and width and height like this

```
 $('#cont').highcharts({
            chart: {
                width: 500,
                height: 300,

                type: 'pie',
                options3d: {
                    enabled: true,
                    alpha: 45
                }
            },
```

cont chart is under container chart but i want chart both in same line check this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUpHZ.png

and also how i add border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [angular gauge demo on the Highcharts website](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-solid/) shows a great example of how to do this.

In their code, they arrange and style their `<div>` elements like this:

```
<div style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
    <div id="container-speed" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>
    <div id="container-rpm" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>
</div>
```

Here's how it looks:

[image]

Now, as far as adding a border to your charts, here is how you would do that:

```
    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge',
        borderColor: 'red',
        borderWidth: 1
    },
```

That would change these charts to:

[image]

Look in the API documentation for more details on how to change other appearance options for the chart, including border radius and background color: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: @user6628729 I don't know why your question was downvoted; it wasn't me that did so.

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` is a block element. Thus it always goes under the previous element. You need to use let's say `<span>` instead of `<p>` and maybe tweak a little bit the sizes of the `spans` so they fit on one line:

```
<div>
  <span id="container">
  </span>
  <span id="cont">
  </span>
</div>
```

and then in css:

```
span#container {
  width: 50%;
}
span#cont {
  width:50%;
}
```

Add the border on the spans in the css.

Comment: when  i add span then margin-left: 490px;
    margin-top: -300px;
    zoom: 90%;
    border-color: blue; does not work

Comment: You shouldn't need the margin-top and margin-left if you use spans. only the width to be small enough for the spans to fit next to each other. If you use the margins as you do, probably the right span goes over and right from the screen and you cannot see the chart.

Comment: What happens if you disable the margins and zoom?

Comment: check this http://i.imgur.com/MSRAXEt.png in this i did not add span also when i add border color then border color also not visible

Answer (score 0):

You should seperate both of the charts or use CSS.

```
.highcharts-container{float:left;width:500px}
```

or

```
.container{float:left;width:500px}
```

will help you.

Comment: Which border color were you talking about ? Charts or Chart Container div ? If Charts add bordercolor property. Otherwise you could do the same via css. border:1px solid red;